# How to replicate two tables with different structures but the same fields?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, database-replication, merge-replication

I have two SQL server databases in different locations.I want to do something like replication.
this is my scenario:
In the first data base I have a table with following structure:

```
tbl_worker
_Name  nvarchar(10)
family nvarchar(20)
State  int
city   int
```

and in second data base I have following table:

```
tbl_employee
_Name   nvarchar(20)
family  nvarchar(15)
Address nvarchar(30)
Tell    nvarchar(14)
State   int
city    int
```

as you see the structure of my tables in two different data bases are not the same.
but I want to replicate just `State and city` fields.
if the `state and city` in the first data base changed in second data base must be changed and vice versa.
How can I do it? Can I do it with replication and how?

Answer (score -2):

When you define the article, you'll have to set the @vertical_partition parameter to true and then add the columns that you want with sp_articlecolumn.