# CSV Export/Import Column Mapping

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a company database (PHP and MYSql) where products needs to be exported and imported regularly. Due to the difference in column between companies, i need to export into their column format and except their format. I am after a script that will map the columns before exporting/importing. Open source would be the preferred choice. I searched the internet all day without any joy. 
Thanks

Comment: You have to prolly write that script. The question is : do you need a cronbased export / import script, or a replication ?

Comment: I have figured out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(sorry I do not have 50 reputation to comment)

You should take a look here 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

And then here
[replication between two tables with different names and which have different column names. Is it possible to create such replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700047/replication-between-two-tables-with-different-names-and-which-have-different-col)